# Dotnet quit unexpectedly rider on Mac ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, rider

[image]

I am using rider, I have a React application at the front end. If I made some changes to the react application the browser refresh. After 2-3 times I see the error as below.

I don't know what is the issue, but I need to restart my system to work it again.

I checked the port it is not used.

```
Process:               dotnet [1628]
Path:                  /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Identifier:            dotnet
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        rider [947]
Responsible:           dotnet [1628]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-07-08 19:56:56.678 +1000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G5033)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        186A27C5-8286-9696-FC7C-34E30B5D41FA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FCB53ECD-760C-4B87-BBF3-1089C5901DAB

Time Awake Since Boot: 6700 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6eb2 WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 82
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108341fab Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker(int, void**, int, unsigned int, WaitMode) + 1243
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010833cbe0 Thread::DoAppropriateWait(int, void**, int, unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 48
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108470fe0 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 64
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108342ec0 Thread::Block(int, PendingSync*) + 32
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010833a8c0 SyncBlock::Wait(int, int) + 544
11  libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010859d5f0 ObjectNative::WaitTimeout(bool, int, Object*) + 192
12  ???                             0x000000010eae07e4 0 + 4541253604
13  ???                             0x000000010eaf5090 0 + 4541337744
14  ???                             0x000000010eaf4f34 0 + 4541337396
15  ???                             0x000000010eb4b156 0 + 4541690198
16  ???                             0x000000010eb4b0fd 0 + 4541690109
17  ???                             0x000000010efc15da 0 + 4546368986
18  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108538c6b CallDescrWorkerInternal + 124
19  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083848e9 MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker(unsigned long const*, unsigned long*, int) + 1657
20  libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010824c6c6 RunMain(MethodDesc*, short, int*, PtrArray**) + 726
21  libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010824ca38 Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod(PtrArray**, int) + 408
22  libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010828ce48 CorHost2::ExecuteAssembly(unsigned int, char16_t const*, int, char16_t const**, unsigned int*) + 504
23  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081c47a2 coreclr_execute_assembly + 226
24  libhostpolicy.dylib             0x0000000107e82b57 0x107e72000 + 68439
25  libhostpolicy.dylib             0x0000000107e83b2e 0x107e72000 + 72494
26  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000107e37a9f 0x107e0e000 + 170655
27  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000107e36d92 0x107e0e000 + 167314
28  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000107e32d9a 0x107e0e000 + 150938
29  dotnet                          0x0000000107de2402 0x107dd6000 + 50178
30  dotnet                          0x0000000107de29f5 0x107dd6000 + 51701
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff67fd33d5 start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810e2c2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c9bf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff680786a6 abort + 127
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081c08ac SEHExceptionThread(void*) + 1884
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810e78a kevent + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b4a70 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ReadBytesFromProcessPipe(int, unsigned char*, int) + 448
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b40e3 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::WorkerThread(void*) + 131
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff681091ea __open + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010823514f TwoWayPipe::WaitForConnection() + 31
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010822c427 DbgTransportSession::TransportWorker() + 167
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010822ae89 DbgTransportSession::TransportWorkerStatic(void*) + 9
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6eb2 WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 82
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108229118 DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop() + 248
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108228fbc DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc() + 284
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108228cd3 DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic(void*) + 131
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6ded WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108471069 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc373 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 179
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc2b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083daed2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6ded WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108471069 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc341 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc2b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083daed2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6ded WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108471069 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc341 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc2b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083daed2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b254b CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6ded WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108471069 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc341 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001084bc2b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083daed2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b252e CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 318
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6bcc CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b6ded WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108471069 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083d75af FinalizerThread::WaitForFinalizerEvent(CLREvent*) + 31
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083d7712 FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadWorker(void*) + 98
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108345883 ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter(ManagedThreadCallState*) + 323
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108345ed0 ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase(void (*)(void*)) + 32
11  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083d79e8 FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadStart(void*) + 504
12  libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810c1e6 __accept + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000108234eae IpcStream::DiagnosticsIpc::Accept(void (*)(char const*, unsigned int)) const + 62
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001083b2610 DiagnosticsServerThread(void*) + 288
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6810b866 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca56e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b252e CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 318
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b21e0 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081b72bd SleepEx + 141
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010836c972 ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire() + 146
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x000000010836c845 ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart(void*) + 181
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x00000001081bdad4 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c72eb _pthread_body + 126
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681ca249 _pthread_start + 66
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff681c640d thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 0):

May sound weird but I got the same error and **Invalid Cache and Restart** worked for me!